# double integral domain setting

Tags: integration

Doing a double integral question always involve transfer the domains into
$a<x<b$ and $ f(x)<y<g(x)$

but sometimes, it's very hard to find these ranges

Like $|x|+|y|\leq 1$
or
$x\leq y\leq x+2$ and $-x\leq y\leq 2-x$

Could anyone transfer these two domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the integral of $f(x,y)$ is:

$$
\int^{0}_{-1}\mathrm{d}x
\int^{x+1}_{-x-1}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y
+
\int^{1}_{0}\mathrm{d}x
\int^{-x+1}_{x-1}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y,
$$

while in the second it is:

$$
\int^{0}_{-1}\mathrm{d}x
\int^{x+2}_{-x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y
+
\int^{1}_{0}\mathrm{d}x
\int^{-x+2}_{x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$

Check in the picture that the second domain is the first one translated along $y$.

[image]

If you meet further difficulties in understanding the first domain, write down $|x|+|y|\le 1$ for

- $x>0,\ y>0$;
- $x<0,\ y>0$;
- $x<0,\ y<0$;
- $x>0,\ y<0$.

You should see four stright lines again then.